# Different meanings of the word "delicate"

Tags: meaning

According to Oxford Learners Dictionaries, delicate has six different meanings. These are some of them:

> 1. easily damaged or broken
> 2. made or formed in a very careful and detailed way

How do I decide one between different meanings in a sentence?

> #### For example:
>
> **The first meaning**: the delicate ecological balance of the rainforest.
>
> **The second meaning**: the delicate mechanisms of a clock.
>
> **Which one?**: Islands often support delicate ecosystems that evolved without any need for defence.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that in most circumstances, you could assign both of those descriptions to the word "delicate". Something that is made in a careful and detailed way is usually easy to damage/break.

To support this, lets use your example:

> Islands often support delicate ecosystems that evolved without any need for defence.

Delicate is describing the ecosystems, so lets use both of the descriptions,

1. Delicate ecosystems --> Must have a perfect balance in order to sustain itself. If one factor is wrong then the ecosystem might be damaged - broken easily.
2. Delicate ecosystems --> Was formed in a very careful/detailed/intricate way

If you are only looking for one description, though, *I would choose number 1*, because the sentence is talking about the precise balance of substance needed to sustain the ecosystem, and how easily it could be damaged.

Comment: I agree. The word "defence" provides the clue that it is "1", and not "2".